# WPF user control not loading properly in WinForms user control

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, visual-studio-2017, mahapps.metro

I am trying to embed a WPF user control (designed using mahapps) in a WinForms user control. I have did this before in vs 2012. But now when i tried to do the same in vs 2017 its not working.

WPF user control is like below:

[image]

If I add it in WinForms user control, it loses all the styles and looks like below.

[image]

Am I missing anything here?

Comment: Any chance of getting a sample of the code you wrote? How exactly are you trying to embed the wpf control?

Comment: I just drag drop the user control ( wpf user control ) into a winforms

Comment: No one can tell what you're missing, given that you did not show any code, [but it does work properly](https://imgur.com/IxoH0BO), both in VS 2017 and 2015.

Comment: We published full project source code showing how to do it. You can find it on [Twitter](https://twitter.com/TradePattern), [YouTube](https://youtu.be/9EqeurfldX8) and [GitHub](https://github.com/jsanalytics/WinformWithWPFUsrControl). Enjoy!